# $\int_0^\pi f(x)^2dx = \int_0^\pi f'(x)^2dx$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in C_{ℝ}([0, \pi])$ satisfy $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$ and $f' \in L^2([0, \pi])$. It can be shown (using Parseval's Theorem and the fact that for the Fourier coefficients we have $c^{f'}_n = inc^f_n$), that $$\int_0^π f(x)²dx ≤ \int_0^π f'(x)²dx.$$
(Ask me for a proof.)

Now I'm asked to determine when actually equality holds, with the hint: "extend $f$ to an odd function on $[-π, π]$".

Without that hint, I arrive at some answer, namely those functions $2ic · \sin(x)$ for any $c ∈ ℝ$. However I never used the hint, really.. So that throws me off. The solutions I have seem to satisfy, but have I missed others?

(In terms of that hint, I do know that for odd functions $f$, the Fourier coefficients satisfy $c^f_{-n} = -c^f_n$, which will probably come into play at some point.)

Comment: Is the notation $f'(x)^2$ standard? Do you mean $(f'(x))^2$?

Comment: I do, some people will find the extra brackets enlightening, others cumbersome. If I had written $f²(x)$, that would have warranted some confusion, but I figured this would be clear enough.

Comment: I don't see any issue with $f'(x)^2$. Except you should use `^2` in $\LaTeX$ instead of the ascii superscript.

Comment: Does the $\mathbb{R}$ in $C_{\mathbb{R}}([0,\pi])$ means that $f$ is real?

Comment: Yes, it does. $f : [0, \pi] \to ℝ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you found with $\sin(x)$ is correct, although I'd say one should remove the imaginary $i$, to have $f$ real. I would suggest something along these lines:

1. Extend $f$ to an odd function and write its Fourier decomposition along sinus functions:
   $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} b_n \sin(nx). $$
   There are no cosinus as $f$ is odd and the coefficients $b_n$ are real since $f$ is real.
2. Write the Fourier decomposition of $f'$.
3. Use Parseval formula to express the integrals
   $$\int_0^\pi f(x)^2 dx \; \text{ and } \; \int_0^\pi f'(x)^2 dx$$
   as infinite sums.
4. Suppose $b_n \neq 0$ for some $n>1$ and prove that the integrals of $f'(x)^2$ is then strictly bigger than that of $f(x)^2$. Conclude.

Comment: I have but one problem: (in your third point) Parseval allows me to express the integrals when integrated over $[-π, \pi]$, right? Perhaps I'm just confused over what $f$ means. Sometimes it means the original function, sometimes the extended, it seems.
Suppose we were to call the extension of $f$, the new function $g : [-π, π] → ℝ$, where would you write a $g$ then?

Comment: Since $g:[-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ is odd, $g^2$ is even and its integral over $[-\pi,\pi]$ is twice the integral of $f$ over $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks! (Was unsure about whether we could immediately say that the square of an odd function is even, but I guess that's quite elementary actually.)